# Azure DevOps REST API Response doesn't contain results when using $top parameter in Wiql request

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query-by-id?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) Azure API to request workitems from our server.
Unfortunately if I set the *$top* parameter in the URL to some value the response doesn't return **any** resulting workitems. I don't get any error message. If don't set the *$top* parameter everything works fine and I get all workitems that matched the query.

My request looks like this:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql?$top=5&api-version=5.1
```

With the request body:

```
SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.Id] > 0 ORDER BY [System.Id] ASC
```

The response looks like this:

```json
{
  "asOf": "2022-02-08T11:20:45.633Z",
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "ID",
      "referenceName": "System.Id",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/fields/System.Id"
    }
  ],
  "queryResultType": "workItem",
  "queryType": "flat",
  "sortColumns": [
    {
      "descending": false,
      "field": {
        "name": "ID",
        "referenceName": "System.Id",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/fields/System.Id"
      }
    }
  ],
  "workItems": []
}
```

Comment: What scripting/programming language are you using to do the query. Many languages would require you to escape the `$` somehow.

Comment: I'm using rust. But that's not the issue. It worked with other parameters and if I put some nonsense behind $top=... I get an error message from the server that the value I set as $top isn't an Int32.

Comment: Was worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be caused by request sql body,
try this one:

```
{
  "query": "SELECT [System.Id] FROM workitems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @project ORDER BY [System.ID] ASC"
}
```

more information see [WIQL syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?toc=%2Fvsts%2Fwork%2Ftrack%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fvsts%2Fwork%2Ftrack%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops#where-clause)

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.